# Does CiviCRM Spark come with a Drupal or Joomla website?

Tags: civicrm-spark

I am considering purchasing CiviCRM Spark to trial it for my organization. I know CiviCRM can be loaded into Drupal, Joomla or Wordpress. I was just wondering whether "spark" is a stand-alone product or if it comes with either website (CMS) platform.

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, Spark cannot handle the public-facing website part. We have locked out those Drupal features. Only the CiviCRM features are available.

However, you can use another service to create your website, then point to your CiviCRM forms hosted on Spark (donation form, newsletter signup, event registration, etc).

CiviCRM Spark aims to help people evaluate and get started with CiviCRM. It is also suitable for smaller organisations (larger ones will hit the contact/email limits and will want to customize it more). For those who outgrow Spark or who have more customization requirements, we recommend contacting a [CiviCRM hosting partner](https://civicrm.org/hosting-providers).

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM always needs a CMS at front end. So unless I update this Answer, you will be given the choice once you sign up. Have asked for clarification to be added to https://civicrm.org/spark via https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/q4nqexud7tyw7q3hxh5s9eykoc

Comment: Spark runs on Drupal CMS however CMS permissions are seriously restricted (no views, no webform eg) so it effectively resembles a headless instance

Comment: @KarinG. To confirm, if I was hoping to build a public facing website with CiviCRM installed in the back end, would it e possible to do so with spark? (Home page, about us, services, membership registration, etc.) or would I need to set up the public facing website separately? I’ve used CiviCRM before with a larger organization but am looking to start up a small social enterprise. Trying to do as much research as possible before I dive in. Thank you,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

[Spark](https://civicrm.org/spark) is just a hosted version of CiviCRM intended for folks who don't have the capacity to install CiviCRM on their own site.  So by definition I don't think it's what you want.  However, there's nothing that Spark has that self-hosted CiviCRM doesn't; in fact, the opposite is true.

Comment: I agree: CiviCRM Spark aims to help people evaluate and get started with CiviCRM. It's also suitable for smaller organisations (larger ones will hit the contact/email limits and will want to customize it more). I would also note that Spark does have regular CiviCRM/Drupal upgrades. Unless an organisation is hosting with a CiviCRM hosting partner who handle the upgrades for them, I would say that this is something that Spark does, and CiviCRM (by default) does not :-)