# Spark Hosting Integration with Existing Wordpress Site

Tags: cms-integration

I have an existing Wordpress Site. I would like to know how do I integrate my Spark hoested site with my Wordpress site. The documen

Answer (score 1):

Check out this answer to a similar question and see if it answers your question:
https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/27915/181